# Two one-to-many relationships in Ruby-On-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have 2 models within Rails, each path has a To field and a From field, both of which reference Location Id but I can't seem to get the relationships set up properly. Any help would be appreciated. I am using Rails 4.2.6.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    #Fields - id, name, description, latitude, longitude

end
```

and

```
class Path < ActiveRecord::Base
    #Fields - id, from, to, distance

    # belongs_to :from_location, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'from'
    # belongs_to :to_location, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'to'

    # belongs_to :from_location, class_name: 'Location'
    # belongs_to :to_location, class_name: 'Location'
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your 'from' and 'to' fields are integers that hold location ids, you should be able to do the following:

```
class Path < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :from_location, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'from'
  belongs_to :to_location, class_name: 'Location', foreign_key: 'to'
end
```

Then for a Path record, you should be able to call .from_location and .to_location to get the Locations.

Have a read of [this](http://www.spacevatican.org/2008/5/6/creating-multiple-associations-with-the-same-table/) for more information.

Comment: When i call .from_location and .to_location I get an error message. 
NoMethodError: undefined method 'from_location' for #<Path:0x007f9366200098> and NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_location' for #<Path:0x007f936621af10>

Comment: I've recreated it and the above is working for me. Have you tried doing this in the rails console?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this in the Rails Console but I still get an error message.

Comment: Can you update the question with your current path.rb, and with the line of code that's causing the NoMethodError please? Also, which version of Rails are you running?

Comment: Thanks. Are the #'s in front of the two belongs_to's in your actual code? If they are it mean's you've commented those two lines out. Remove the two #'s then give it another try.

Comment: I've uncommented the lines out and then re ran the code. It now runs but just returns nil.

Comment: Cool. This is probably just that you don't have a Location with an id that matches the Path's from/to value, i.e. if you have a Path where from = 1, you will need a Location with an id of 1.

Comment: I have 2 locations, one with Id 1 and one with Id 2. the location has to=2 and from=1. So I'm not sure why it's returning nil

Comment: Hmm, not sure why but I'm now getting the result I want. Thanks for your help.